# HTML + CSS: Add a class/id to simple text

Tags: html, css

I'm currently stuck at a probably very trivial problem:

I have a simple HTML/CSS page with a text:

```
<head></head>
<body>
    This is a Text about Foobar.
</body>
```

How is it possible to assign a CSS-class/id to the word `Text` without breaking the format? Let's say I want to add the class `.yellow` to it, which displays the text with a yellow background.

I think I got something blocking my mind cause it can't be that difficult... But all I can google (mostly trivial tutorials) uses CSS just on usual HTML-elements like `<p>` or `<b>` which would break my format.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are missing out on `<span>` tag.
Try this out:

```
<head></head>
<body>
    This is a <span class="yellow">Text</span> about Foobar.
</body>
```

And in CSS:

```
.yellow{
color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: exactly what i was gonna say, span is like a joker of html

Answer (score 4):

Use an inline element. Span is purpose build for that. Alternately, if you wish to have semantic meaning behind your highlighted section, you can re-style `<em>` or `<strong>` with something like:

```
strong.highlight{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to wrap the section in a span like:

```
<span>This is a <span class='yellow'>Text</span> about Foobar.</span>
```

See a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/dZZfB/

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The HTML for Example:

```
<center><span class="t1">Test1</span></center>
```

The CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .t1 {
        color: white; 
        text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
    }
</style>
```